# Extract UTF-8 data using pyspark from db2

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, db2, databricks

Using pyspark I'm trying to extract utf-8 data from db2.

Code used:

```
remote_table = spark.read.format("jdbc")\
  .option("driver", "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver")\
  .option("url", "jdbc:db2://hostname:port/dbName")\
  .option("query", "select name from db.table where id = '123'")\
  .option("user", user_name)\
  .option("password", password)\
  .option("encoding", "UTF-8")\
  .option("characterEncoding", "UTF-8")\
  .load()
```

Result is:

```
+----------+
|   name   |
+----------+
|M� A     |
+----------+
```

Expected output:

```
+----------+
|   name   |
+----------+
|Mª A      |
+----------+
```

I have also tried setting these properties, which didn't really work.

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.spark.executor.extraJavaOptions", 'Ddb2.jcc.charsetDecoderEncoder=3')
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.spark.driver.extraJavaOptions", 'Ddb2.jcc.charsetDecoderEncoder=3')
```

Kindly help.

Comment: to display the data, the operating-system shell must first (before connecting to the database) be configured properly .  For linux/unix, the LANG environment variable value must reflect a UTF-8 locale.  For microsoft windows, the active codepage must do the same (c.f. chcp).

Comment: I tried using a different tool (Informatica) to extract the data and it shows the expected data. So is it right to guess the configuration should be correct? Else it should not work regardless of tool used.

Comment: It seems you have not understood, that the display of the data will be incorrect when your client side terminal (or shell) is incorrectly configured. This is a FAQ.